# "Underclassman" vs. "upperclassman" for juniors in high school/college

Tags: word-usage

Is a junior a underclassman or an upperclassman? According to Oxford University Press, an underclassman is

> a student in high school or college who is not a senior

However, also according to Oxford University Press, an upperclassman is

> a junior or senior in high school or college

in the US (I live in the US). These definitions are contradictory for juniors, so under which stratum is a junior?

Comment: I can't give you a factually backed answer, but in my high school an underclassman was a freshman or sophomore, and an upperclassman was a junior or senior.

Comment: @Azuaron that what I thought my high school classified them as too, until they sent out an email where they called 9th, 10th, and 11th graders "underclassmen."

Comment: I don't recall any school of mine being impolitic enough as to classify anyone as *underclass*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conventionally, the online dictionaries— [MM](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/upperclassman), [MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/upperclassman), [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/upperclassman), [AHD](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=upperclassman), [CED](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/upperclassman), [LDOCE](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/upperclassman)… — all provide that *upperclassmen* in the U.S. are "juniors and seniors" or "third and fourth year" or "in the last two years" of their high school or college career. All except ODO define the other half as *underclassmen*. A rarer alternative is *lowerclassman*. These are demonstrably not the exclusive use of those terms, however.

There is no requirement that words and their apparent inverses form tidy, mutually exclusive classifications. A *new car* is one that is purchased from the manufacturer that has never been owned by anyone but the manufacturer, in contrast to a *used car* (or, if you must, *pre-owned car*). But if I replace my car with a used car, it is still *my new car*, and a "new" car relative to the other cars in the household.

In actual usage, not only can *upperclassman* and *underclassman* be asymmetric, but both vary in use depending on context: sometimes sophomores get lumped with the upper division, and sometimes juniors with the lower. It is not uncommon to use *upperclassman* or *upperclass* as a shorthand for *non-freshman*, for example, in academic advising and in campus housing, because the freshman / frosh / first-year experience is the relative outlier in how those programs are organized. Consider

- [Harvard](https://college.harvard.edu/academics/advising-counseling/upperclassman-advising) — Freshmen Advising vs. Upperclassman Advising
- [CalTech](https://deans.caltech.edu/Services/AcademicSupport) — Rules for Freshman vs. Rules for Upperclassmen
- [Pitt housing](https://www.pc.pitt.edu/housing/options.php) — Freshmen Housing, Upperclass Housing, and Graduate Student Housing
- [USC housing](https://housing.usc.edu/index.php/section/undergraduate-upperclassmen/) - Freshman Housing, Undergraduate Upperclassmen Housing, Grad and Family Housing

By the same token, *underclassman* is sometimes shorthand for *non-senior*, perhaps in [doling out scholarships](http://econ.columbia.edu/announcements)— *We are looking to support up to five underclassmen (juniors preferred…)* (Columbia) — or [regulating course registration](http://economics.yale.edu/senior-seminars)— *Senior majors… who do not preregister, as well as underclassmen and students who are not majors…, will be able to shop advanced lecture courses or seminars that have not filled up during preregistration.* (Yale).

Absent any other context, I would assume *underclassman* refers to a frosh or sophomore, and *upperclassman* to a junior or senior. But I do not shudder when they are used as relative terms.